# SQL Find consecutive numbers in rows

Tags: sql

I have a query that return one shown.

[image]

I need to list rows of minimum and maximum number if it's sequence. This should result in the following output:
please help, I am not good in English. thanks

[image]

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I don't think that this can be achieved using just SQL

Comment: @AhmadWabbi of cause it can :)

Comment: When it comes to sample data, 1 digit numbers are much easier to read than 8+ digit numbers. Make it easy to assist you!

Comment: Do you want min and max per `Kalaf` consecutive sequence? Why you have three rows of the 61313396 `kalaf` value?

Comment: @RadimBača He wants the min and max for consequtive numbers in ID. 92,93,94.

Comment: @plaidDK How can you detect a sequence without a loop? When I said 'just SQL', I meant without some kind of programming languages like PL/SQL or Transact-SQL.

Comment: @plaidDK I do not see any 92, 93, 94 value in ID

Comment: @RadimBača Line 3,4,5 in ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cross apply to find max and min rows, and dense_rank to group you sequence.

**SQL Update** Thanks to Tony for simplifying my cross applys ;)

```
declare @myt table (id int,number bigint, tip int, kalaf int)

insert into @myt
values
(971545701,4110897922,411,41108979),
(971578550,6131339133,613,61313391),
(971578992,6131339402,613,61313394),
(971578993,6131339403,613,61313394),
(971578994,6131339404,613,61313394),
(971579095,6131339627,613,61313396),
(971579100,6131339632,613,61313396),
(971579102,6131339634,613,61313396);

WITH T
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (
            ORDER BY ID
            ) - ID AS Grp
    FROM @myt
    )
    ,test
AS (
    SELECT MIN(ID) AS RangeStart
        ,MAX(ID) AS RangeEnd
        ,MIN(number) AS minNum
        ,MAX(number) AS maxNum
    FROM T
    GROUP BY Grp
    )
SELECT t.RangeStart AS ID
    ,t.minNum
    ,t.maxNum
    ,f.tip
    ,f.kalaf
FROM test t
INNER JOIN @myt f ON t.RangeStart = f.id
Order by ID
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Forgive me for not the prettiest SQL

Comment: you can get rid of the cross apply's:

WITH T AS
(
SELECT *,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID) - ID AS Grp
FROM #TIPS
)

,test as (
SELECT MIN(ID) AS RangeStart, 
       MAX(ID) AS RangeEnd,
    MIN(number) AS minNum,
    MAX(number) AS maxNum
FROM T
GROUP BY Grp
)

select t.RangeStart as ID,
 t.minNum,
 t.maxNum,
 f.tip,
 f.kalaf 
from test t
inner join #TIPS f on t.RangeStart = f.id;

Comment: @TonyMathew Thanks for simplifying. I updated my answer so its more optimize. The first one, was just written as what came to my mind :) Nevertheless both works.